# Что мешает установить на Windows 10 модуль pyglut?

Tags: python, opengl, pip, pyglut

Пытаюсь установить модуль `pyglut` для отрисовки икосаэдра с помощью библиотеки `OpenGL`. Но установки не получается.

Моя версия Python 3.7.6, pip имеет версию 23.0.1.

Трэйсбэк ошибки:

```
Collecting pyglut
  Using cached pyglut-1.0.0.zip (603 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 36, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\zlatt\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qnyt0xzm\pyglut_720181f5b6054599aa3fd05a5dcd443d\setup.py", line 28, in <module>
          long_description = file.read()
        File "c:\Users\zlatt\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
          return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 1544: character maps to <undefined>
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: А имя компьютера, случаем, не с кириллицей? Хотя нет... Такое ощущение, что `setup.py` пытался открыть файл с кодировкой cp1251, а тот в другой кодировке. Скорее всего, проблема в `setup.py` - если в `open` не указывается кодировка, то используется системная, т.е. `cp1251`, а не, предположительная, `utf-8`

Comment: Простите, что за имя? Комп не в локальной сети (если что)

Comment: @gil9red, интересно. Такой вопрос: а как мне изменить кодировку и где? Просто я пытаюсь установить отсутствующий у меня модуль. Если же начну меня что-то в `setup.py`, то, предполагаю, проблемы будут в других модулях (или при их установке)